# Why doesn't C# DateTime string formatting work?

Tags: c#, .net

The following code doesn't format the time properly. All I want is minutes:seconds:milliseconds_with_3_decimals but no matter what formatting I choose it gets ignored and the time is displayed with default formatting.

```
Log(LogMsgType.Normal, String.Format("+{0:mm:ss.fff} ", DateTime.Now.Subtract(latest)));
```

[image: Code output]

Comment: [DateTime.Now Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx).

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Not related to the formatting question, but you should use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`.  Otherwise your calculations could be off when Daylight Saving Time starts or stops.  Even better, use a [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.aspx) class, especially if you actually have requirements for fine-grained precision like you showed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to look into formatting of `TimeSpan`, not `DateTime`. This was new in .NET 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010). See: [MSDN: Custom `TimeSpan` Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx).

I would try something like:

```
String.Format("+{0:mm':'ss'.'fff} ", DateTime.Now - latest)
```

(Better check first that it's never over 60 minutes, otherwise you will lose the most significant part of the time span.)

***NOTE:*** If you're on .NET 3.5 or earlier, this won't work as `TimeSpan` wasn't `IFormattable` in those versions. In that case I recommend:

```
var span = DateTime.Now - latest;
  ...
String.Format("+{0:D2}:{1:D2}.{2:D3} ", span.Minutes, span.Seconds, span.Milliseconds)
```

Comment: If it was new in .NET 4.0 then it's not very useful to me considering that I am working with .NET 3.5 SP1.

Also, why wouldn't it work with DateTime, my code seems to be conforming to the MSDN examples of DateTime formatting?

Comment: `Subtract` returns a `TimeSpan`, not a `DateTime`, so you need to look at how to format a `TimeSpan`, which is different from formatting a `DateTime`.

Comment: DateTime.Subtract(DateTime) returns TimeSpan, DateTime.Subtract(TimeSpan) returns DateTime (for completeness and clarity)

Comment: Thanks. So the code was pretty much correct, but useless due to the .NET version. Bummer.

Your workaround work great though.

Comment: @Hungi well, #1, your question doesnt mention that. But even if it did, I would urge you to reconsider, particularly given that Win8 and Win8.1 come with .Net 4 but *not* .Net 3.5. (That is, using 3.5 requires a resist but 4.0 does not)

Comment: @KekuSemau was right about the subtraction overload. If you from `Now` subtract another `DateTime` instance of time, the result will be a `TimeSpan`, whereas if you from `Now` subtract some `TimeSpan` period, the result will another `DateTime`. Mathematically, these are the two kinds of "inverses" we get from one asymmetrical addition `DateTime operator +(DateTime x, TimeSpan y)` defined.

Comment: @Billy ONeal well #1 I have nothing against moving away from the outdated .NET 3.5 but I'm bound by what my university uses on its computers so that's that.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
@"+{0:mm\:ss\.fff} "
```

You have to escape the colon and period

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it has no effect, it's exactly as before.